# How to prove that a group homomorphism is bijective

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $(G,+)$ be a finitely generated abelian group of rank $r$ such that every $w\in G$ can be written in the form $w=n_0w_0+n_1w_1+\cdots+n_{r-1}w_{r-1}$ for some integers $n_0,\dots,n_{r-1}$.

Let $\zeta:(G,+)→(\mathbb Z^{r},+)$, $w→\zeta(w)=(n_0,n_1,\dots,n_{r-1})$, be a homomorphism. Prove that $ζ$ is bijective.

Comment: Technically that's not a question. Just saying...

Comment: Then how I can do that

Comment: I don't know. Gotta wait for someone else, sorry.

Comment: I think what @GitGud means is that your question should be phrased as something like "How do I prove this is bijective?" As far as that is concerned, recall that, by definition, a bijection is one to one and onto. Maybe that will help you.

Comment: @ Brent J: I know that, but I have no an idea to start.

Comment: @Chaos: Please [look at the revisions I made](http://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/7903503e-313b-4753-85f5-e651ea1bcf6c/view-source) to see how to format your posts better in the future. You can find some good starting points on how to format mathematics on the site [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020). [This AMS reference](ftp://ftp.ams.org/ams/doc/amsmath/short-math-guide.pdf) is very useful.

Comment: Ok and thanking you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** It is already written in your question, in different words, that it is surjective. To show that it's injective, note that if you assume otherwise, you have a certain $w \in G$ that can be represented in more than one way as a sum of $w_i$. Subtract the two representations and you'll get a nontrivial representation of $0$. Use this to express one of the $w_i$'s as an expression involving the others and get a contradiction to the given rank of the group.

Answer (score 2):

If by *rank* you mean [the torsion-free or Prüfer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_of_an_abelian_group) rank, then it is almost immediate: since any element in $\,\Bbb Z^r\,$ can be (*uniquely* , btw) written as $\,(n_0,n_1,...,n_{r-1})\;,\;\;n_j\in\Bbb Z\,$ , then $\,\zeta\,$ is clearly surjective. Injectivity follows at once from the above written definition of free-torsion rank.

Comment: I understood rank as "the smallest size of a set of generators".

Comment: Yes @YoniRozenshein , but the "free-torsion" part is a must, otherwise the whole think is clearly false.

Comment: Yes, I mean the torsion-free rank.